# php file not running in command line... but works when run on localhost

Tags: php, curl, command-line

I created a really simple small php script that I was hoping to run in the command line on my MacOSX terminal.

If I just type `echo "test"` that gets outputted just fine.

Now I added a curl request to that script to grab some data from an API and then type `print_r $result`.

Unfortunately the result is never outputted into the command line. If I now run the exact same php file in my MAMP localhost, everything works fine and the content is outputted correctly.

This is my code:

```
require 'connection.php';

$store = new connection('danny', 'https://store-bgf5e.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/', 'XXXXX');
$customers = $store->get('/customers');

foreach($customers AS $customer) {
    print "------ Getting Adresses for: " . $customer['first_name'] . ' '         . $customer['last_name'] . ' -------';
    if( isset($customer['addresses']['resource']) ) {
        print_r($store->get($customer['addresses']['resource']));
    }
}

exit;
```

I know that the API returns the addresses just fine so the call definitely works.

This is what Curl is saying:

```
*   Trying 63.141.159.120...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to store-bgf5e.mybigcommerce.com (63.141.159.120) port   443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /Applications/MAMP/Library/OpenSSL/cert.pem CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=AU; ST=New South Wales; L=Ultimo; O=Bigcommerce Pty Ltd; CN=*.mybigcommerce.com
*  start date: Jun  4 00:00:00 2015 GMT
*  expire date: Sep  1 12:00:00 2018 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "store-bgf5e.mybigcommerce.com" matched cert's "*.mybigcommerce.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /api/v2/customers HTTP/1.1
Host: store-bgf5e.mybigcommerce.com
Authorization: Basic     ZGFubnk6M2QyNjE5NTdjZGNjMTNlYmU1MTJiNDRiMjE1NGJiZGZmMGRjNTUxMw==
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: openresty
< Date: Fri, 05 May 2017 19:26:27 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Set-Cookie: fornax_anonymousId=0ff167a5-e158-4ff8-8962-67b19bd4271b; expires=Mon, 03-May-2027 19:26:27 GMT; path=/; domain=.store-bgf5e.mybigcommerce.com
< Last-Modified: Thu, 13 Apr 2017 22:34:54 +0000
< X-BC-ApiLimit-Remaining: 2147483622
< X-BC-Store-Version: 7.6.0
< 
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host store-bgf5e.mybigcommerce.com left intact
```

To me it looks like Curl is executing everything correctly. It's almost like the successful curl request prevents any other PHP code from running. I would expect to see addresses being printed out to the command line because of "print_r".

Thanks in advance for any tips you might have.

Comment: You need to post the script.

Comment: Code por favor.

Comment: Updated the question, sorry guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out. I was using this framework to connect to the BigCommerce API: https://github.com/adambilsing/PHP-cURL-lib-for-Bigcommerce-API/blob/master/connection.php

In the `http_parse_headers` method of the `connection` class there is an if statement on line 54:

```
if ($retVal['X-Bc-Apilimit-Remaining'] <= 100) {
    sleep(300);
}
```

This would trigger the script to go to sleep even if `$retVal['X-Bc-Apilimit-Remaining']` is `null`.

Changing it to this fixed the issue:

```
if ( isset($retVal['X-Bc-Apilimit-Remaining']) && $retVal['X-Bc-Apilimit-Remaining'] <= 100) {
    sleep(300);
}
```

It's pretty obvious once you look into it. I wasn't even aware that there is a sleep command in php.

Thanks for everybody who was trying to make sense of this :)

Answer (score 0):

may you can try to [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) your result and see what happend. For your curl response I did not see any content-length header, I think curl return empty string.

and please can you post your php code ?